# php - how to get the server timezone for windows?

Tags: php, windows, timezone

how to get the server timezone on a windows server with PHP?

for linux:

```
$systemTimeZone = system('date +%Z');
```

*nix system:

```
$systemTimeZone = popen("date +%Z");
```

windows:

```
$systemTimeZone = ???
```

greez & thx,
  sky...

EDIT:
i know about the php function like:

```
date_default_timezone_get()
date('T')
\DateTime::timezone
```

but all of this build-in function from PHP are referenz to the setting in the php.ini. i want to know the real used timezone from the OS.

i have try to use the windows command-line tool

```
systeminfo
```

but this is to slow for call and parsing. another command line tool i have testet is:

```
tzutil /g
```

this is not the timezone format what i want, in my case i get this:

```
$:> tzutil /g
W. Europe Standard Time
```

any other ideas for me ?

Answer (score 5):

What about the built-in function?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

Answer (score 1):

I had just now the same error, and found no better solution then using a selfmade mapping. For windows I used this:

```
// this array can be filled up with whatever you need
$timezones = array(
      'GMT' => 'Europe/London'
    , '0' => 'Europe/London'
    , '1' => 'Europe/London'
    , 'GMT Standard Time' => 'Europe/London'
    , '2' => 'Europe/Berlin'
    , 'W. Europe Standard Time' => 'Europe/Berlin'
);

// getting the timezone    
$timezone = exec('tzutil /g');

// and setting it accordingly
if( array_key_exists($timezone, $timezones)) {      
    echo("> timezone identified as " . $timezones[$timezone] . "\n");
    date_default_timezone_set($timezones[$timezone]);
} else {
    die("Unknown Timezone: " . $timezone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you the servers timezone abbreviation:

```
$systemTimeZone = date("T");
echo $systemTimeZone;
```

E.g. EST, MDT ...

Comment: TZ abbriviations are ambiguous around the world.  See http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/